# How to skip condition check in where clause if parameter value is null or blank?

Tags: sql, oracle

Need a small help. I am working on a stored procedure call which runs a select. (I cant put in the actual select due to business constraints but I will give you  a dummy scenario.)

Here is a stored procedure:

```
Procedure checkData (name IN VARCHAR2, vehicle IN VARCHAR2, retval OUT VARCHAR2, retdata OUT returnData)
```

The select inside it gets values from a text box field which is used for search. The select is like this,

```
select *
from myTable tab
WHERE tab.vehicle = vehicle
  AND tab.name = name
```

Now what the issue is when the user specifies only one value out of the 2 mentioned above, the search fails as it tries to check the details based on `AND` condition

For example, if user provides only vehicle value, lets say `'BMW'` then the result should contain all the entries for vehicle. But what happens is as the user has not provided name value, it takes it as `''` or null and the query doesn't return anything as it doesn't find any data matching `name = ''` condition.

So I tried below,

```
select *
from myTable tab
WHERE tab.vehicle = vehicle
AND IF name IS NOT NULL OR name != ''
tab.name = name
```

But it says,

> ORA-00920:invalid relational operator.

So what can I do to skip the second check if the value for name is either null or ''. In that specific case, I simply want to skip the second check and return result based on vehicle values only.

I can't use `OR` condition because I will need to get exact matches too when both the parameters are available. I am using Oracle DB.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After putting some debugs I have come to know that the value is NOT null actually. It's always coming as '' (blank/empty)

Comment: `varchar2` empty string is the same as `null` in Oracle Database. It is unclear what you mean by is not null, but blank/empty. Is that in the client application?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But the problem is resolved now. Below is what I used to get it to work, `select * from myTable tab
WHERE 
tab.vehicle=vehicle
AND tab.name like '%'||UPPER(name)||'%'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns vehicle and name in your table are always not null, you can try something like this:

```
select *
from myTable tab
WHERE nvl(vehicle, tab.vehicle) = tab.vehicle
  AND nvl(name, tab.name) = tab.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable tab
WHERE tab.vehicle=vehicle 
AND IFNULL(tab.name,1) = IF(tab.name IS NULL,1, name)
```